# How to cast app screen/mirror screen to chromecast

Tags: flutter

I want to cast my app screen on chromecast. I have implemented the casting function using the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_cast
however it casts only videos from url as it uses the following code to load media:

```
await _controller.loadMedia('https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4');
```

So how can I pass my app screen as media source.
Thanks

Comment: you can just use the in-built android screencast option?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if and how exactly this will work, but worth a try -

1. Host an HTTP server on your mobile device (or perhaps HTTPS might be necessary for chromecast).
2. You can get the device IP using the [wifi_info_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_info_flutter) package.
3. Record the widget (the top-level widget for casting the app). You can use the [widget_recorder](https://pub.dev/documentation/widget_recorder/latest/widget_recorder/WidgetRecorderPeriodicController-class.html) package for this. It can return image byte data periodically.
4. You can serve the above image byte data stream **somehow**, serving a single image is easy but I am not sure about stream data.
5. Use `_controller.loadMedia('http://deviceip:port/appscreen')`.